# Is it possible to use google drive to upload file from other user to my drive?

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

I am building an app where user uploads there pdf file or image file to our server, but that will increase size in server. So is there any method so that user will upload those file directly to google drive of host user, not to end user. I have searched a lot and found that can only upload file to your own google drive. If this is possible and then how??

Comment: The use case you are describing is one that is probably best solved with the Google Cloud Storage API: https://cloud.google.com/storage/ . This isn't "Google Drive" but gives you a storage system for large blobs of data (so that the files are not stored locally on your particular server). Access is credentialed based on the project/applications's account.

Comment: that's paid. Is any other such api which is available freely

Comment: so is Google Drive (beyond a certain free quota). There is no free lunch. However, this pricing is extremely low/competitive.

Comment: yes thanks for this information